# How to Rate/Like YouTube comment with youtube-v3?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I've found guide on rating videos but so far there is no such guide available on rating the comments? Can any one help?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: May I ask what guide you found on rating videos? I'd like to take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's safe to conclude this feature does not exist for the following reasons,

The otherwise thorough API documentation makes no mention of this feature. I highly doubt youtube/google would forget to document a feature. This question has been asked several times before on SO; all of which have no accepted answer (1, 2, 3). With the oldest question being 10 months old, it's very unlikely no one would have found this feature if it did exist. Youtube is a common target of voter-bots and hence it would make sense to not offer an API entry-point as a first line of defense. The official Youtube (android) app offers no comment-upvote option but only flag and reply options. If a comment-upvote feature would exist, you'd think Youtube would show it off in their own app.