# Youtube api v3 Add like to comment

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I am needing to add like of comment

```
  var g = GetTopComments(service, videoid)[0];
      g.Snippet.TopLevelComment.Snippet.ViewerRating = "like";
      var re = service.CommentThreads.Update(g, "snippet").Execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is currently supported as there's no mention of it in the Youtube API. You can [like the video itself](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate) but not the comments. This has been asked in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209300/how-to-rate-like-youtube-comment-with-youtube-v3) and has received no answer. 
Try filing a feature request [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request).